# How to install ATI drivers on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: drivers

I need to install ATI drivers on my Ubuntu 16.10.

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

gave me this:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]
```

How do I install them?

Answer (score 1):

> System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

- wait a few seconds for the probe to finish ...
- pick the AMD driver from the list ...
- save and reboot

Above is the suggested method ... If desired drivers are not shown in above list here are instructions to install necessary AMD native drivers

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Summary

issue this

```
lspci -vvnn | grep VGA
```

to confirm you have an AMD graphics card then issue these steps

backup current setup

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK

sudo apt-get purge fglrx* # purge prior installs ... reboot if it found any
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

Generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING!

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

now reboot then issue this to confirm you are using AMD drivers

```
fglrxinfo
```

Done ... for details see link above

Comment: I did that, it only picks up Wireless driver and some Unknown driver. It doesn't help, I still have problems with video. Perhaps my laptop is too old and it doesn't have driver support or something (HP Compaq 6715s)?

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and above, the AMD Catalyst or fglrx driver is no longer supported by AMD, or in Ubuntu.